# Intent overlap the dialog box?

Tags: android, android-intent

I write this code to make a dialogue box with 'yes' and 'no' option appear after pressing the 'OK' button. The'Yes'should lead users to a 'ShowResult' activity where it will show the user's input from the 'Main Activity'; and the 'No' will just have a toast message saying 'you have cancelled the submission.'

The problem is when the 'OK'button is clicked, the dialogue pops up for a second, then the intent will show up, covering the dialogue box.

If I click return and click 'Yes', the activity won't show the user inputs.  This is the Main activity code I have been struggling on.  I hope to not change much of the whole structure since this is a school project and we should be using simple techniques.

```
 Button btnOK;
    EditText txtName;
    EditText txtCoursename;
    RadioButton rdnYear1;
    RadioButton rdnYear2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
        btnOK.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowResult.class);
        txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        txtCoursename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCoursename);
        rdnYear1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdnYear1);
        rdnYear2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdnYear2);

        intent.putExtra("Name", txtName.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("Course Name", txtCoursename.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("Year 1", rdnYear1.isChecked());
        intent.putExtra("Year 2", rdnYear2.isChecked());


        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);

            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnOK:
                builder.setTitle("You are submitting your data.");
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure?");
                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You cancelled the submission.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                });
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowResult.class));

                    }
                });

                builder.show();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: base from your Yes button code from the alert dialog, you're not starting the intent you have created `intent` which has your extras or strings. It should be `startActivity(intent)`

Comment: Just tried the starActivity(intent), but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

try putting the intent part inside the switch case & do add startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

You have already created an intent at the very start of "onClick". Try using the same intent instead of creating another new one after postive clicks. Also, I didn't see a **break** statement in your switch case which needs to be followed.

Answer (score 0):

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowResult.class));

                }
            });

            builder.show();
        }
```

here you are creating a new intent with no data

you should use your previously created intent where you used putExtra()

use this :

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
```

////////////////////////////
                        startActivity(intent);
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
                    }
                });

```
            builder.show();
        }
```